# Embedded Dynamic PDF Chart

Tags: pdf, charts

I am currently working on a PDF form for a client. They have requested a dynamic pie chart that would change dependent on he values in various fields.
There are some restrictions which might make this impossible, the PDF's are used on iPads and also will not have any access to internet, so my question is would this be possible at all?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are demos floating around from Acrobat 9 times, when the link to Flash was new, and it used Flash to create the pie chart. Besides of extensive programming (the link between Acrobat JavaScript and Flash is nothing for the faint at heart), this approach is wonky, and not reliable, as even on a computer, you now have to provide Flash player separately. And on tablets, you won't have Flash anyway.

A second approach, which I have implemented in a few cases is to dynamically create annotations based on the field values (polygon, polyline, etc.). This works pretty well with the top end PDF viewers on computers. The problem for your scenario is that at the moment, even the top end PDF viewer for iDevices (PDFExpert by Readdle) does not support the Annotation object. Might be worth a feature request at Readdle, in order to support the Annotation object.

A third approach would be creating the graphic in an external application (or a helper) as PDF, and then use the importIcon method to display it in a prepared Button field. This method is supported in PDFExport. The issue in this scenario is to get the data out of the PDF, and create the graphic in an external application. It should be possible somehow, but for the implementation you would have to get an experienced expert…

Conclusion: Essentially possible, but the use of iDevices may make it impossible. The third approach appears to me as the most promising.

Comment: Great thanks for all the info, yea I suspected with apples restrictions on flash and xfa forms that it might not be possible.